# HTML row fill vertical space

Tags: html

Just doing some experiments with HTML, I wonder, why do the second line does not fill the remaining space. Why is the table not stretched vertically?

```
<table width="100%" border="1" height="100%">
  <tr>
      <td align=center>Line 1
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="90%" >
      <td>Line 2
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just tested this (by adding html open and closed tags to the top and bottom) and it does fill the entire page.  There must be some other part of your code that has this block modified.  The problem must be with some encapsulating tag, or a tag that comes after this table.

Comment: IE7, which could explain things I admit.

Answer (score 3):

Block elements, `TABLE` being one of them, expand to the size of their CONTENTS.

`100%` has no context in this case. Give it a value in numbers.

Comment: So this is true only for the height and not the width?

Comment: 100% height = 100% height OF THE PARENT. Since the parent (BODY) is also sized to its content, the table *IS* 100% height. 100% width = the browser width.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <body style="height: 100%;">
        <table style="height: 100%;">
        ...
```

in order to force all parents of the `table` element to expand over the available vertical space (which will eliminate the need to use `absolute` positioning).

Works in Firefox 28, IE 11 and Chromium 34 (and hence probably Google Chrome as well)

Source:
http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/howtoset100tableheightinhtml.aspx

Comment: worked in css (didn't try html)
```html, body, table { height: 100%; }```